# How disable a node of a Extjs 6.0.0. treelist?

Tags: javascript, extjs, treelist, extjs6

I'm using [sencha extjs 6.0.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0). I have a `treelist` like [here](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-list). I want to some of its leaf be disable.

**Is it possible**? If true, how?

Answer (score 1):

According to doc, the nodes of the tree don't have "disabled" property. Here is another thread discuting the same problem for ExtJS 4, solving it with some CSS :

[Is there any way to disable nodes of treeview in ExtJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261919/is-there-any-way-to-disable-nodes-of-treeview-in-extjs-4)